# How to write a video DVD on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, video, dvd, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended DVD Creator](https://superuser.com/questions/12293/recommended-dvd-creator)

A friend of mine has a few `.avi` and `.flv` files (of mixed resolution and frame rate), and he'd like to convert them and burn a video DVD (`VIDEO_TS` etc.) on Windows XP. He wants to define the DVD track/title boundaries one-by-one, manually. He needs a program for that, preferably free-to-use software, preferably localized to Hungarian. He is a novice user, he'd prefer an integrated solution which is intuitive, doesn't ask unnecessary technical questions, and does the job the most straightforward way. Which program do you recommend?